# Codeigniter: URI you submitted has disallowed characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

My URL is:

```
https://example.com/c3dlZXRfcmFqdmk5MUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbQ=
```

When I remove `=` then it works fine.

I have this in `config.php`

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Error:

```
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

How can I allow `=` or `==` signs in URI?

I have tried it by changing this:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-='; // added = sign at the end
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In /project-folder-name/application/config/config.php configure this variable:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=';
```

it also  works for @ character

Comment: should not system be omitted? the path is incorrect i think. it should be project_folder/application/config/config.php

Comment: This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will get a warning message.  As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
 as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_- . Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.

Answer (score 10):

change in `config.php` file

```php
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=';
```

and

```php
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

It works for me. Try it yourself!

Comment: $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; - did not help and created more bugs. Adding characters in under permitted uri chars did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

In CI open directory at
`project-folder-name/application/config/config.php` and configure the variable `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=';
```

This will work for all special characters

Answer (score 2):

i have got this in address bar

**O9SPVKocvz6Ph7mT+ulXzMhYV2VDao5gfL9BWtdMKdOBL4PnSLc5E8nIBYnj4hdTpaBUUgFmMX+3X24CfzZ3Rw==**

change in config.php file

**use this**

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-\=+';

its working fine

Comment: Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 16

Filename: core/URI.php

not working for me.. CI v3.1.5

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: You need to escape the dash character (by placing a backslash in front of it) in the string as it's used in a Regex. Meaning that it takes a bare (unescaped) dash to indicate a character range.

Comment: can u show me example that what u try to do so I can help u bro

Answer (score 2):

first of all you have to encode your id that is pass in url, then in controller you have to decode the id.
view:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>Cinvoice/imei_invoice/<?php echo base64_encode($invoice_list['invoice_id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Final Invoice By Ware House">Primary Order</a>
```

**Controller:**

when you call fuction that is in library

```
$content = $CI->linvoice->get_imei(base64_decode($invoice_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my **CI version 3.11** i solved by this :

in `application/config/config.php`  i changed

```
$config[‘permitted_uri_chars’] = ‘a-z 0-9~%.:_\\-‘;
```

to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

and problem solved.

My URL was something like this : `example.com/product/45/kotlin_toturial(by_avasam.ir) _in_99_lessons`

.

Comment: This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will get a warning message.  As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
 as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_- . Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the config.php file

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-=&';

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=&';
```

and

`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`