# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters. URL is `https://www.carlo.in/car_offers#getDiscounts?key=test`

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, parameter-passing

I need to echo the value of key which is test.
se url in picture.

URL is `https://www.carlo.in/car_offers#getDiscounts?key=test`

> [image: ggest]

is any way to get data like this ?

> `<?php echo $_GET['key'];?>` and Output : test.

Comment: do you need $_GET['key'] ?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: problem is #getDiscounts in url

Comment: what's the output now?

Comment: php error undefined variable key

Comment: $_GET['key'] works, have you try it? Show your php code please

Comment: Have you a $key in your code?

Comment: Anything after `#` is ignored(we call it as URL fragment) and not sent to the server. The URL is poorly formed. It should indeed be `https://www.carlo.in/car_offers?key=test#getDiscounts`

Comment: vivek_23 i think you are right. let me try

Comment: `<input style="border:1px solid #3879FF;" type="text" class="form-control" name="requirement"  value="<?php echo $_GET['key'];?>" placeholder="Car Make/Model name">`

Comment: vivek_23 not working error is The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: @RajendraSingh I can't tell much without seeing the source code or your server setup.

Comment: code is <a href="https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts" rel="nofollow">

Comment: Do you work in Codeigniter?

Comment: yes , codeigniter

Comment: @RajendraSingh: I think your code should be `<a href="https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts" rel="nofollow">`.

Comment: let me try. its not same

Comment: not working url overrided like https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts

Comment: @RajendraSingh `car-offers` 2 times? Shouldn't it be `https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts`?

Comment: its added automatically when i click twice on link. but its working https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts

Comment: @RajendraSingh: Can you show us the PHP code that generates the link?

Comment: @RajendraSingh Ok, glad it's working now. But you need to fix the 2 times addition of `car-offers` in your `href`s.

Comment: display code is -  <input style="border:1px solid #3879FF;" type="text" class="form-control" name="requirement" value= "<?php echo isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '';?>" placeholder="Car Make/Model name"> and link code is - <a href="https://www.carlo.in/car-offers/?key=Ford_Endeavour#getDiscounts" rel="nofollow">

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780905/codeigniter-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780905/codeigniter-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters) Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

you can code like this

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
```

and if you echo $key, the result will be

```
echo $key;
// test
```

P/S : do not forget to sanitize if you are using the $key to query something from your DB.

Comment: i want to use value of key in this input  code is here > `<input style="border:1px solid #3879FF;" type="text" class="form-control" name="requirement"  value="<?php echo $_GET['key'];?>" placeholder="Car Make/Model name">`

Answer (score 0):

No way with PHP because the parameter is a part of hash, You can place the parameter in HTML with Javascript or You can send the parameter to your server with Javascript and place some PHP answer in HTML then.