# Get value to php hyperlink in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make link action to controller in codeigniter after get response from ajax. I need a variable from ajax response to put in the link to controller, and then in controller, I need to operate update process. I've tried using php link but it doesn't work. Error shows `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters`.

Here's the script

```
          $.ajax({
              type : "GET",
              url  : "<?php echo admin_url().'leads/data_status'; ?>",
              success : function(response2){
                 var data2 = JSON.parse(response2);
                 var html = '';
                 var a;

                 for(a=0; a<data2.length; a++)
                 {

                    html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data2[a].name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data2[a].company+'</td>'+
                                '<td><a href="<?php echo admin_url().'leads/trash/status='?>'+data2[a].status+'&id='+data2[a].id+'">Back</a></td>'+
                             '</tr>';

                 }

              }
           })
```

Here's controller script

```
public function trash(){
    $id=$this->input->get('id');
    $status=$this->input->get('status');

    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'last_status' => null
    );

    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update(db_prefix() . 'leads', $data);

    redirect('admin');
}
```

Do you know how to fix the code ?

Thanks

Comment: [Codeigniter: URI you submitted has disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780905/codeigniter-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters)

Comment: Hi @N'Bayramberdiyev, I've tried it before, but it's still show same error

Comment: Then try to encode URL parameters using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Decode them before use in your controller. And where do you output `html` variable in your AJAX call?

Comment: you can check in your response which url you are getting and then try to run in your browser and then check what is the issue in your url...

Comment: Can you try this way
assign a variable before ajax function var adminurl = '<?php echo admin_url()?>';
pass the variable inside ajax like this url:adminurl + "leads/data_status",

Comment: have you added any data to your ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are concatination issues in your code, I have udpated the string can you please try with this one

```
html += '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+data2[a].name+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+data2[a].company+'</td>'+
    '<td><a href="<?php echo admin_url();?>leads/trash/status='+data2[a].status+'&id='+data2[a].id+'">Back</a></td>'+
'</tr>';
```

or with storing url in a variable like

```
url = "<?php echo admin_url();?>leads/trash/";
url += 'status='+data2[a].status;
url += '&id='+data2[a].id;

html += '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+data2[a].name+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+data2[a].company+'</td>'+
    '<td><a href="'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'">Back</a></td>'+
'</tr>';
```

don't forget to use `urldecode` in php if you use `encodeURIComponent`

```
$id=urldecode($this->input->get('id'));
$status=urldecode($this->input->get('status'));
```

Comment: Hi @Prateik, thank you, I've found where's the code